# Pyinstaller creates large EXE file when I include PIL import

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I am doing the below imports in my code

```
import os
import ctypes
import logging
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from time import sleep
from shutil import copyfile
from selenium import webdriver
import tkinter.messagebox as message
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.edge.options as edgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import  expected_conditions as EC
from winreg import OpenKey,QueryValueEx,KEY_READ
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
```

If I comment out my 5th import, ie PIL, then i am getting an exe with around 10MB size. But If I try to include PIL, then pyinstaller takes lot of time and finally generates a large (around 230MB) exe file. Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Large file sizes with pyinstaller seems to be a pretty common topic, have you done any research?

Comment: Not only I use``from PIL import Image``,but also ``from PIL import ImageGrab``.But my app is only 20M.

Comment: Trace what else PyInstaller is including?